# How to handle the touches event in subView

Tags: iphone, subview, touches

Here is my code:

mainView:

```
NSArray *btArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1",@"1",@"1",@"1",@"1",nil];
ButtonBarComponent *bottomeButtonBar = [[ButtonBarComponent alloc] initButtonBarComponentWithButtonArray:btArray];
bottomeButtonBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 340, 320, 200);
[self.view addSubview:bottomeButtonBar];
```

subView:

```
-(id)initButtonBarComponentWithButtonArray:(NSArray *)btArray {
self = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 340, 320, 200)];
self.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
}
```

but why I cant run the code in touches event?

Comment: Is this Java? Objective C? What language?

Comment: where you are using the array in initButtonBarComponentWithButtonArray method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try setting user interaction enabled for your view and subview